# Issues within my Logic with a basic MatLab function

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to create a simple MatLab script, just learning the basics and I am having some trouble with a custom function.

I am attempting to create a rectangle through a function via lines and I've come up with the following:

```
function rectfunction(x,y,w,h)
x1 = [x,x+w,x+w,x,x,x+w,x+w,x]
y1 = [y+h,y+h,y,y,y,y,y+h,y]

line([x1,y1])

%top
%line([x,y+h],[x+w,y+h])
%bottom
%line([x+w,y],[x,y])
%left
%line([x,y],[x+w,y])
%right
%line([x+w,y+h],[x+w,y])
```

The commented out code at the end was the version that *mostly* works, only it had troubles if the x/y or w/h values were different. I was told to use a vector as I have attempted to, only nothing now seems to be drawing whatsoever.

I am calling this all within another script as such:

```
axis([0 100 0 100])
rectfunction(20,20,60,60)
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

edit: I should probably add that this is a part of an early university assignment, I can't simply use "rectangle" as it defeats the purpose of the workshop

also, here's an example of how my commented out code would handle differing values wrongly:

[image]

It does, however, draw just fine if x/y and w/h use the same values.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many points in your function, you just need:

```
function rectfunction(x,y,w,h)
x1 = [x,x+w,x+w,x,x];
y1 = [y+h,y+h,y,y,y+h];

line(x1,y1)
```

and it should just work, regardless of whether x/y and w/h use the same values or not.